# React collapsible menu component that should expand when I click on a category title but won't show the children links

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I created a component for a collapsible navigation menu. This menu has a map of children categories and each one of these categories has a list of links.

This menu has a button to expand and collapse the navigation menu panel.

When I click in one of the category titles the menu should expand and at the same time show the corresponding links, however with this code only expands the navigation menu panel but not show the children links.

The collapsed structure is something like this:

```
Cat A
Cat B
Cat C
```

The expanded structure with children links is something like this:

```
Category A
|
|--Link A1
|--Link A2
|--Link A3

Category B
|
|--Link B1
|--Link B2
|--Link B3

Category C
|
|--Link C1
|--Link C2
|--Link C3
```

This is the menu component:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { NavItem } from "./NavItem";

export function Navigation({
  menuItems,
}) {
  const [opened, setPanelOpened] = useState(false);

  return (
    <nav className={opened ? "expanded" : "collapsed"}>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setPanelOpened(!opened);
        }}
      >
        Toggle Menu
      </button>

      {menuItems.map((item) => (
        <NavItem menuItem={item} setPanelOpened={setPanelOpened} panelOpened={opened} />
      ))}
    </nav>
  );
}
```

This is the NavItem component for categories:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export function NavItem({
  menuItem,
  panelOpened,
  setPanelOpened,
}) {
  const [categoryOpened, setCategoryOpened] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div
      // If category is opened, should toggle a class to show / hide the children elements
      className={categoryOpened ? "opened" : "closed"}
    >
      <h2
        onClick={() => {
          // Should display the children menu items when I click the button
          setCategoryOpened(!categoryOpened);
          if (!panelOpened) {
            setPanelOpened(true);
          }
        }}
      >
        Parent Category
      </h2>

      {menuItem.children?.map((subItem) => (
        <a href={subItem.link}>
          {subItem.label}
        </a>
      ))}
    </div>
)
}
```

`setCategoryOpened(!categoryOpened)` won't work at the same time with `setPanelOpened(true)`, only expands the menu and won't shows the children category items. How can I trigger both hooks at the same time?

When I click on a category title the menu should expand and show the corresponding children links at the same time, but only menu expansion happens, I have to click again to show the children links

Answer (score 0):

You're using two clicks events, if you want you can attach an useEffect hook that depends on your parent state, and when it changes the children set the states as true and open. As I cannot run your code, it's hard to debug, but the hint is to start putting `console.log()` to see where's the issue. Keep in mind that `setState()` method is asynchronous, so if you're trying to get the updated value in a sync function maybe it has the outdated value at that moment.

You can debug this as I told you with logs everywhere, to see what's happening. Hope it helps, if not please provide a code sandbox or a working snippet for us to debug properly your code.

I attached a example of the useEffect hook implemented on your component.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export function NavItem({
  menuItem,
  panelOpened,
  setPanelOpened,
}) {
  const [categoryOpened, setCategoryOpened] = useState(false);
  
  useEffect(()=> {
    if(panelOpened) setCategoryOpened(true)
  }, [panelOpened])

  return (
    <div
      // If category is opened, should toggle a class to show / hide the children elements
      className={categoryOpened ? "opened" : "closed"}
    >
      <h2
        onClick={() => {
          // Should display the children menu items when I click the button
          setCategoryOpened(!categoryOpened);
          if (!panelOpened) {
            setPanelOpened(true);
          }
        }}
      >
        Parent Category
      </h2>

      {menuItem.children?.map((subItem) => (
        <a href={subItem.link}>
          {subItem.label}
        </a>
      ))}
    </div>
)
}
```

Comment: The useEffect hook works great dealing with more than one useState hooks, however this expands all the menu categories at once. Do you know a way to show only the menu category sub items when I click on the corresponding category title?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want to achieve, as the default behaviour for your component should be `click to open menu > click to open submenu` if you want some submenu to be displayed by default, you can try to filter it with the index (you can do it in the map method as `.map((item, index) => ...)`). That's one way you could set the first one (index = 0) as open by default.

Answer (score 0):

use `stopPropagation(e)` in onclick. React can get confused when you import 2 states. We use it to avoid this.

ep :

`onclick = {e => e.stopPropagation() ... }`